# In signing up there's no problem but when I sign in it's returning to catch block | nodejs expressjs | mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, express

> //----------------db----------------------
> app.use(bodyParser.json());
> app.use(express.static('public'));
> app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
> mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/signup');
>
> var db = mongoose.connection;
>
> db.on('error',()=>console.log("error in connection"));
> db.once('open',()=>console.log("connected succesfulllly"));
>
> app.post("/signup",(req,res)=>{
> var name = req.body.name;
> var email = req.body.uemail;
> var password = req.body.upassword;
>
> var data = {
> "name" : name,
> "email" : email,
> "password" : password
> }
> db.collection('users').insertOne(data,(err,collection)=>{
> if(err){
> throw err;
> }
> console.log("record inserted");
> });
>
> return res.redirect("/");
> })
>
> //-------------------------signin check
> app.post("/signin",async(req,res) => {
> try{
> const email = req.body.email;
> const password = req.body.password;
>
> const useremail = users.findOne({email:email});
>
> if(useremail.password === password){
> res.redirect("/");
> }
> else{
> res.send("password incorrect");
> }
>
> res.send(useremail);
> console.log(useremail);
>
> }
> catch{
> res.send("in catch block invalid Email");
> }
> })
>
> /*------------end of db------------*
>
> //server create
> app.listen(port, () =>{ console.log(`hi, port: ${port}`); })

//This is my app.js code. I'm having problem in "signin check". There's no problem with Sign up details are also stored in mongodb compass. Help me with sign in. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the first glance, since you are using native mongodb, in signing query should look like this:

```
const useremail = await db.collection('users').findOne({email:email});
```

You had 2 mistakes there, first syntax was wrong since I assume you do not have user model(You do insertOne with same thing).
Also you need await keyword since database operations are async and they return promise. Without await value of useremail  would be undefined, thus causing the error

Comment: You are right there's no user model. As you told I did signing query. But my app crashed. Sorry to say but I didn't understood where to put await keyword. HELP Please

Comment: @user21199397 Update this line const useremail = users.findOne({email:email}); with the line I wrote above